# Commandline method to switch network connection on and off in OSX

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, wifi

I frequently tether using my iPhone using a Wifi Hotspot and every once in a while the connection stops working. To fix this, I have to enable and disable the hotspot and then enable/disable the Wifi on the MBP (OSX 10.8.3).

I was hoping to automate this on the MBP. Would you know of a command line way to do this ? The command should switch the wifi off (if it's on) and then switch it back on (slightly different from simply toggling the Wifi connection).

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [ifconfig](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ifconfig.8.html):

```
$ sudo ifconfig en1 down    # take network interface down
$ sudo ifconfig en1 up      # bring it back up again
```

This assumes that your WiFi network is on `en1` - obviously change this to `en1` or `en2` or whatever, as needed.

Comment: Awesome, this totally works : `sudo ifconfig en1 down && sudo ifconfig en1 up`. Thanks !!